# What is causing my 3rd person camera to lose rotation on the z axis?

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I've been working on a 3rd person camera on unity for a couple weeks, but I've pretty much hit a wall, specifically to do with my camera's rotation. When I rotate it on its x and y axis it won't have a problem, but when it gets to the z axis (180 degree's on the x axis), it loses the ability to rotate at all. This is the code I've been using:

```
void Start()
{
    //controlls camera relevent to player position
    offset = new Vector3(Player.position.x - 3.0f, Player.position.y + 2.0f, 0);
    offset = transform.position - Player.position;
    localtoworldY = transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.left);

}

void Update()
{
    //need to give proper rotation of the camera around the player
    offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
    offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, localtoworldY) * offset;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(offset, Vector3.up);

    transform.position = Player.position + offset;
    transform.LookAt(Player.position);

    print(transform.rotation);


    // If the y axis go to 6.4 positive, it should stop but not stop working, same as if the camera hits a mesh or terrain.


    // If the camera changes in any direction regardless of x or y axis,player should be able to move relative to 
    // the direction that the player is pressing (IE when the player press left, the Homicida malorum will move left regardless of
    // the angle of the camera).

}
```

}
Any advice or an explanation as to why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this line:

```
localtoworldY = transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.left);
```

1. `TransformPoint` applies the object's translation, so the result of this call will be different depending on where your object is in the scene. To transform a direction (sensitive to rotation but ignoring translation & scale), use `TransformDirection` instead.
2. You're performing it only once, in `Start()`, so it's not updating the direction as the rotation changes. Imagine you've turned around 180 degrees - what was once on your left is now on your right, but your axis of rotation does not reflect this change.
3. The vector it looks like you're trying to get is already available to you as a built-in: `-transform.right`

So you can skip this entirely, and correct the line in `Update()` to:

```
offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(
             Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, 
             -transform.right
         ) * offset;
```